# Eclipse DI does not create a custom object annotated with Created

Tags: java, dependency-injection, eclipse-rcp, e4

I'm developing an Eclipse RCP application based on 4.4 Luna version.

I have the following classes:

```
public class NewProjectDialog extends TitleAreaDialog {
@Inject
private ProjectManager projectManager; 
// some code  
}
```

and

```
@Creatable
@Singleton
public class ProjectManager {
// some Code
}
```

When I run the application and open `NewProjectDialog` the following exception is thrown:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: org.eclipse.e4.core.di.
InjectionException: Unable to process "NewProjectDialog.projectManager": 
no actual value was found for the argument "ProjectManager".
```

Apart `@Creatable` annotation must I do something more to make Eclipse DI instantiate this class when it cannot find it in the context?

Comment: Is `ProjectManager` in a different plugin? If so the package containing it would have to be in the Export-Package list for the plugin.

Comment: No, they are both in the same plug-in, just in different packages. `NewProjectDialog` is created via `ContextInjectionFactory`, but I guess this does not matter.

Comment: Does ProjectManager have a `public` constructor? It looks like one is required (with @Inject if there are any parameters).

Comment: `ProjectManager` does not contain any constructor, but two injected fields. I have tried to create the default constructor with `@Inject` annotation, but I still have the same exception.

Comment: Possibly it is having trouble with the injected fields not being found in the context.

Comment: Thank you @greg-449 . The problem was in an injected field. I forgot `@Named` for it and the exception message distracted attention from that.

Answer (score 0):

I have also face the same issue and the answer already given by greg-449 is in the comment section of the question is correct. Yes, it is problem in injecting/creating the fields of such objects.